# Variable with getter/setter cannot have initial value, on overridden stored property

Tags: swift

When creating a stored property with Observing Accessors, I can specify a default value. However, when overriding a stored property and its Accessors I cannot specify a default value.

> Variable with getter/setter cannot have initial value.

Which seems very strange, as this is NOT a computed property with a getter/setter, but a set of Observing Accessors on a stored property!

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

internal var test: Float = 32.0 {
    willSet {

    }

    didSet {

    }
}
```

The first view controller compiles fine, with a stored property initialized to 32.0

```
class SecondViewController: FirstViewController {

override var test: Float = 64.0 {
    willSet {

    }

    didSet {

    }
}
```

The second view controller does not compile, as the 'computed property' is being given an initial value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In swift you are able to override properties only with computed properties (which are not able to have default values) with same type. In your case, if you wish override `test` property in `SecondViewController` you need write something like this:

```
override var test: Float {
    get {
        return super.test
    }
    set {
        super.test = newValue
    }
}
```

And there is no way to override `didSet`/`willSet` observers directly; you may do this by write other methods invoked in observers and just override them:

FirstViewController:

```
internal var test: Float = 32.0 {
    willSet {
        test_WillSet(newValue)
    }
    didSet {
        test_DidSet(oldValue)
    }
}

func test_WillSet(newValue: Float) {}
func test_DidSet(oldValue: Float) {}
```

SecondViewController:

```
override func test_WillSet(newValue: Float) {
    super.test_WillSet(newValue)
}
override func test_DidSet(oldValue: Float) {
    super.test_DidSet(oldValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has been asked a long time ago but I came up with a slightly different solution and it works exactly as you wanted. You have a property in the first ViewController then in the inherited one you override it and have observers set on it in the form of didSet.

So in the FirstViewController you have a property like in the example below:

```
var myNumber: Double = 20.00
```

Then in the SecondViewController which inherits from FirstViewController you override it as follows:

```
override var myNumber: Double {
     didSet {
             //Here you can update UI or whatever you want to do once the property changes
             //Print its value
             print("Value of myNumber is : \(myNumber)")
            }
```

I hope this will help someone with the above issue as this is a nice and easy way to solve the problem mentioned above.