# Subclass with IBInspectable color property - override not possible

Tags: swift, subclass

I have a custom UIView class with an IBInspectable color property:

```
class MyParent: UIView {
    // use CGColor for setting background (a gradient), and IBInspectable UIColor to choose color in Interface Builder
    var color1: CGColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    var color2: CGColort = UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    @IBInspectable var UIcolor1: UIColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            color1 = UIcolor1.cgColor
        }
    }

    // INIT: Set gradient with color1/2 for the background of MyParent view
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [color1, color2]
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

**Update for clarification:** It is done in that way, to be able to pick a color in Interface Builder (only possible with UIColor), but then as the background of the view is a gradient, it need to be converted into a CGColor. Therefore the didSet does the job, and after picking a UIColor in IB, the background changes respectively.

Now I would like to have another custom UIView, which is a subclass of MyParent and I would like to set another default UIcolor1, but I get an error:

```
class MySubclass: MyParent {
    // override UIcolor1
    override var UIcolor1: UIColor = UIColor.blue

    // ...
}
```

The following error:

```
Cannot override the stored property 'UIcolor1'
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do here if you don't want to set in the init your color

```
class MySubclass: MyParent {
// override UIcolor1
  override var UIcolor1: UIColor {
      get {
          return .blue
      }
      set {
          color1 = newValue.cgColor
      }
   }
// ...
}
```

**after your code edit**

I think there's no need with this usage of subclassing your view. Here is the working code

```
@IBDesignable
class MyParent: UIView {
    // use CGColor for setting background, and IBInspectable UIColor to choose color in Interface Builder
    var color1: UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet {
            gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2]
        }
    }

   var color2: CGColor = UIColor.green.cgColor

   @IBInspectable var inspectableColor1: UIColor {
       get {
           return color1
       }
       set {
           color1 = newValue
       }
   }

   private var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
   // INIT: Set color1 for the background of MyParent view
   // ...
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      setupLayer()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      setupLayer()
  }

  func setupLayer() {
      gradientLayer.frame = bounds
      gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2]
      layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. While it takes away the error, it changes the property to a computed property, and the didSet from the parent class doesn't work anymore (if changing the color in IB, it doesn't update anymore)

Comment: I've edited my code, added in the setter `color1 = newValue.cgColor` this should do what you've asked

Comment: I did this, but if I change the color in IB, nothing happens

Comment: what exactly needs to happen?

Comment: please check my updated post: I added the init, where the gradient is set. So what should happen is that the newly set (in IB) UIColor1 of the subclass would change the color1 value and then the IB would update the background of the view to the new color

Comment: I think now it's pretty much what you've been asking

Comment: thanks for the update. unfortunately, I need the subclassing, but I think it won't be possible to have the IBInspectable override with default value, I just found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877587

Comment: you can subclass: `class MySubclass: MyParent {
    override var inspectableColor1: UIColor {
        get {
            return color1
        }
        set {
            color1 = newValue
        }
    }
}`